# Fullpage.js - stop mouse scrolling on last but one section

Tags: fullpage.js

I have 5 fullpage sections and scrolling set by whole sections. Everything works fine.

But i need, if visitor is on 4th section and scrolls down, that web not scroll down to last section. I want access to this last section only by click on button in 4th section. This button is done and functional, but i dont now, how to disable automatic scrolling to last section.

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the scrolling in the last section by using the method

```
fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down');
```

More about it on the docs:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setallowscrollingboolean-directions

So, you can use it on a callback such as afterLoad:

```
afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction){
    var numSections = document.querySelectorAll('.fp-section').length;

    // Is the afterload firing for the last section?
    if(destination.index === numSections -1){
       fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false, 'down');
    }

    // for all other sections, we enable scrolling again in case it was off
    else{
       fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true, 'down');
    }
}
```

Then on the button you can use the method moveTo:

```
//moving to section 4
fullpage_api.moveTo(4)
```

More about the method on the docs:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide

Comment: Thanks so much! Only small thing for others - small typing error "destionation.index" should by "destination.index" and for my purposes "numSections -1" should be "numSections -2", because indexing on sections starts on 0.

Comment: If there are 4 sections, numSections = 4, index of las section = 3 :)